# Retrieve total value of column by SQL query and show by Java fx

Tags: java, sql-server

I am trying to fetch the total value from SQl query and it's giving me error that column name does not exist, where tbl_internet is table name and billFine is column whose datatype is double and total_fine is the label name.

```
try {
        String sql = "select sum(billFine) from tbl_internet ";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next())
        {
            String sum= rs.getString("sum(billFine)");
            total_fine.setText(sum);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Error Description

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver > Column name not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## About the Error

The error is telling you that jdbc could not find the SQL column name. You are trying to get a column that is literally named "sum(billFine)", a name you do not have in your table.

## Solution

Use the following query `String sql = "select sum(billFine) as amount from tbl_internet ";`

Now the resultSet that will return, will have a column named **"amount"** with the sum value stored in it.

Now instead of `getString()`, you need to use `getDouble()`, as `sum()` should return a double.

then to fetch the amount using `rs.getDouble("amount");`

Comment: both of ways works fine but the way you are implementing is better since in indexes there is chance of giving wrong column index

Comment: @HuwaizaTahir Yes, I believe it is better to use names and not indices as it conveys the programmers thought in a clearer way.

Answer (score 1):

Just access the value by the column index in the `ResultSet` (see also https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(int)). I prefer using the indices for all queries but `SELECT *` queries, since this way you avoid having to hardcode the column names multiple times and also avoid passing the wrong value like in this scenario:

```
String sum = rs.getString(1);
```

You probably should access the sum as `int`, `long` or `double` though

```
double sum = rs.getDouble(1);
total_fine.setText(Double.toString(sum));
```

Comment: It will work, but IMO it is more prone to bugs in the future, if you are to change a query, you might need to change the indices as well.

Comment: One way or another you need to hardcode the info about the query somewhere. Either you use indices and avoid typos in the column aliases or you use aliases to avoid having to change the code when you change the column order in the result...